# multiple load tags in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filter

**directory structure**

```
app_one
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        filter_one.py
app_two
    templates
        app_two
            template_one.py
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        filter_two.py
```

There are some filters in filter_one.py, Also there are some filters in filter_two.py. And every usages of these filter in the template_one.html were working.

Then I added two more filters in filter_one.py

**filter_one.py**

```
@register.filter
def f1(val):
    return val['evaluations'][0]['range']

@register.filter
def f2(val)
    return val['evaluations'][1]['data-type']
```

**template_one.html**

```
{% load filter_one %}
{% load filter_two %}
{{ value | f1 }}
```

This gives an error "Invalid Filter: f1".

**But it works when I move the templates to filter_two.py**

**Can't figure out the logic behind it!**

Comment: Make sure that `app1` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Both apps are in included in Installed Apps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually need to write **.py**, same as in usual python module import. Just write your code as follows:

```
{% load filter_one %}
{% load filter_two %}
```

If you want to save some lines, you can actually load tags in one line, with module names separated by space:

```
{% load filter_one filter_two %}
```

Comment: Yeah that fine, but the above load tags w/o the .py should work ?

Comment: Yes, it should. I will slightly edit my answer if it confuses you.

Comment: NO, my question is if I remove .py from my load tags still its not working, it cant find the new filters(f1 and f2),why ?

Comment: All right, I am totally confused right now.
If you are sure you have proper folder structure for both cases (filter_on, filter_two), I have two suggestions. First - try checking for name clashes, something might screw things up. If that does not help - try writing `{% load f1 from filter_two %}`, that may probably fail earlier and yield a better error message (probably).
Oh, and by the way: please, update your question to provide stack trace and full error message.